# Mortise lock on sliding door installation

Tags: doors, lock, mortise

My mortise lock on my sliding door fell into the door itself so I have no idea what replacement mortise to get. I bought an e2014 with a 45 degree lock and although I did get it into the door something feels off with the lock. It’s very fussy and only locks if it’s angled perfectly. It’s very hard to describe. How do I find the right mortise for my door? If I change the mortise to a vertical kind will that do anything different to how the door locks?

https://files.fm/f/8gd68jycb

Comment: a picture would hep

Comment: I added a link to the new installed mortise that is giving me trouble. Hopefully the video works!

Comment: PRIME-LINE E 2014 Mortise Lock - Adjustable, Spring-Loaded Hook Latch Projection for Sliding Patio Doors Constructed of Wood, Aluminum and Vinyl, 3-11/16”, 45 Degree Keyway, Round Face

Comment: thanks for the Video The lock on the Frame side needs hight adjustment

Comment: Is that the thing the latch latches into? That needs height adjustment or the mortise part needs height adjustment?

Comment: Yes, the prime line e2014 is the one I bought at Home Depot. I am unsure if it’s the right fit. It seems to be but something is off with the locking.

Comment: Watch this video how to adjust it https://www.amazon.com/Prime-Line-2014-Mortise-Lock-Spring-Loaded/dp/B000I1CL8A?th=1

Comment: That was the first video I went to and it really didn’t help much. I’m wondering if I need the vertical type instead of the 45 degree. I wish I hadn’t dropped the original mortis down into the door. I am so clueless. It just doesn’t feel right after continually adjusting it. It’s really hard to actually lock into place.

Comment: In your Video it appears it is hiting the lock bar on the frame, but it is to fast to see it well, do another video and go slow when closng the door.

Comment: https://files.fm/f/5b6dedrfp

Comment: Great, that Video helps, now it looks like the latch does not extends deep enough. Did you try adjusting it with the adjustment screw, or push on the door close really hard

Comment: I’ve tried everything. I’m giving up on it. I think it’s the wrong model. It’s truly not latching properly. Who is the best kind of person to repair this? Just a regular handyman?

Comment: OK, get a Pitbull and tie him to the door.

Comment: I have another suggestion. Take nail polish and apply it to the lock, to see where it touches or not